# Sveltekit & Fetching data to use within HTML

Tags: javascript, fetch, svelte, sveltekit

I feel like i'm missing something obvious but I can't for the life of me figure out what it is i'm missing. I'm essentially trying to perform a fetch call in a  call, and then use that data within the page. I can't get the data to actually work on the page though. It works if I console.log it within the  tag, but once I try in the HTML I get undefined. Any idea what i'm doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

```
<script>
let gameinfo = async (chardata) => {
        chardata = toTitleCase(chardata);

        const gamedetails = await fetch('https://api.igdb.com/v4/games', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: `fields *;\nwhere name= "${chardata}";`
        })
            .then((res) => res.json())
            .then((gamedata) => {
                gamedata.map((e) => {
                    console.log(e);
                });
                return gamedata;
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });
    };

    export let gameJson = gameinfo('Snatcher');
</script>
```

which returns a console logs of the mapped variable.

and the call in the html:

```
<main>
    <div class="mainContent">
        <div class="contentBlock">
                {console.log(gameJson)}
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

which returns undefined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you didn’t return `gamedetails`.

For `gameinfo`, it should be called in `onMount`‘s callback with `await` to get `gameJson`

```
import { onMount } from 'svelte'

let gameinfo = async (chardata) => {
  chardata = toTitleCase(chardata);

  const gamedetails = await fetch('https://api.igdb.com/v4/games', …)

  // you can verify it’s not undefined here
  console.log('check:', gamedetails)
  return gamedetails
}

export let gameJson

onMount(async () => {
  gameJson = await gameinfo('Snatcher')
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! :) Where would I input the return gamedetails? I tried at the end of the gamedetails function but I was still getting undefined :(

Comment: Just update my answer

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, its much appreciated. Its not even hitting the console.log within the gameinfo function, oddly. Weird bug!!! Thanks agai